# Python: Conditional OR

Tags: python, while-loop, conditional-operator

I have the following `while` loop:

```
accuracy = 0.0001    #  Or whatever
loop_limit = True
limit = 100
#  Main loop:
while abs(P - P_old).max() > accuracy or (if loop_limit: count > limit):
```

Needless to say it doesn't work. What I want, is for the `or` statement to be checked only when `loop_limit = True`.

I could put an `if` statement into the `while` loop which resets the count variable on every pass of the loop only if `loop_limit = True`, but that would have to check loop_limit on every pass of the `while` loop and i want to avoid that. (The loop is going to be running millions of times over and every time saver helps). I have a feeling there is a neat way of doing this.

Edit:

Note that (P - P_old) is a numpy array, hence the `.max()` I forgot to mention that and i don't want to remove it now since it has been referenced in an answer already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
while abs(P - P_old) > accuracy or (loop_limit and count > limit):
```

By the way, what's that `max()` supposed to do there? it doesn't even compile...

Comment: Yup. That does it. Cheers.

Comment: I'm debugging someone elses code so I haven't thought about that yet. I't compiles all right for me though. I'm using Enthought Canopy and IPython though so it might smooth out some errors. I'm just about to take a look at it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that P is a numpy array.